# Apollo Federation - Entity field always returns object, not null

Tags: graphql, apollo, federation, apollo-federation

I'm playing with Apollo Federation, and I'm using an entity from another service (`File` entity), in which this entity has the following resolver:

```
File: {
                    __resolveReference(reference, context) {
                        return null;
                    }
                },
```

Now, in spite of hard-coding / returning `null` from the resolver, I still get the object containing specified fields, which are all null.

[image: "image" field is null]

This is the query I'm sending:

[image]

Is this normal behavior?

Thanks!